# (401) Login Required Error for retrieve a users from Google apps domain?

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, google-api-php-client, google-directory-api

how to retrieve a all users from a Google apps doamin . I have tried with the following coed but google return error like "Error calling GET https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users?domain=domainname.com: (401) Login Required "

```
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'E:\wamp\www\Google APIs\google-api-php-client\src');
ini_set("memory_limit", -1);
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/Google/Client.php';
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/Google/Service/Drive.php';
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/Google/Service/Oauth2.php';
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/Google/Service/Directory.php';

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("Google+ PHP Starter Application");
$client->setClientId('42X74XXXXXercontent.com');
$client->setClientSecret('OxzVALdXwd');
$client->setRedirectUri('http://localhost/Google%20APIs/index.php');
$client->setAccessType("offline");
$client->setApprovalPrompt("force");
$client->setDeveloperKey("AIXXXXXJDUdX48");
$SCOPES = array(
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile');
$client->setScopes($SCOPES);
$token = '{"access_token":"ya29.1.AAXXXaeTg","token_type":"Bearer","expires_in":3600,"id_token":"eyJhbXXXXXXX9cEjDMUMe6PVrgo","refresh_token":"1\/sN-XXXXX5qdIGMeEW95tJv-0a1ujWk","created":1397878356}';
$decoded = json_decode($token);
$client->setAccessToken($token);
if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
    $client->refreshToken($decoded->refresh_token);
}
$adminsdk = new Google_Service_Directory($client);
$users_list = $adminsdk->users->listUsers(array('domain'='domainon.info'));
```

Note : I have Perform a authorization with

```
$SCOPES = array(
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile');
```

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

You say you're performing the authorization for those scopes, but those scopes aren't included in the client. Make sure you include this code before you run `$client->refreshToken()`:

```
$client->setScopes($SCOPES);
```

Comment: I also tried with scopes . But still having same problem please help

Comment: Please edit the original post with the code you're using, including where you're adding the `setScopes` code.